# Moving data between fields in destination table in T-SQL MERGE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, merge, sql-update

I have a SQL MERGE statement that does an UPDATE if a value exists (and an INSERT if it does). I'd like to record the last few "historical" values in the row when an UPDATE happens, sort of like this:

```
MERGE into desttable as dest
USING sourcetable as src
on src.ref = dest.ref

WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET dest.oldvalue3=dest.oldvalue2, 
dest.oldvalue2=dest.oldvalue1, 
dest.oldvalue1=dest.value, 
dest.value=src.newvalue

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ...
```

... so essentially, the existing "value" is shuffled down to "oldvalue1", "oldvalue1" becomes "oldvalue2" etc. However, when I run this, every column gets set to "value" - the UPDATE statement is obviously setting all the fields at once. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `left outer join desttable`  in the `using` clause and use columns from `desttable` as source to the update.

```
MERGE INTO desttable AS dest
USING (SELECT s.ref,
              s.newvalue,
              d.oldvalue2,
              d.oldvalue1,
              d.value 
       FROM sourcetable AS s
         LEFT OUTER JOIN desttable AS d
           ON s.ref = d.ref) AS src
ON src.ref = dest.ref
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET dest.oldvalue3=src.oldvalue2, 
           dest.oldvalue2=src.oldvalue1, 
           dest.oldvalue1=src.value, 
           dest.value=src.newvalue
;
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/114412/